# Latest XGboost and Sklearn giving error

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

```
xgb=XGBClassifier(objective="binary:logistic", n_estimators=100, random_state=42, eval_metric=["auc"])
```

### xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in **call**(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, **kwargs)
    461 
    462     def get_indices(self, i):
--> 463         """Row and column indices of the i'th bicluster.
    464 
    465         Only works if `rows_` and `columns_` attributes exist.

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in **repr**(self, N_CHAR_MAX)
    277                 right_lim = re.match(regex, repr_[::-1]).end()
    278 
--> 279             ellipsis = '...'
    280             if left_lim + len(ellipsis) < len(repr_) - right_lim:
    281                 # Only add ellipsis if it results in a shorter repr

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/pprint.py in pformat(self, object)
    142     def pformat(self, object):
    143         sio = _StringIO()
--> 144         self._format(object, sio, 0, 0, {}, 0)
    145         return sio.getvalue()
    146

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/pprint.py in _format(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level)
    159             self._readable = False
    160             return
--> 161         rep = self._repr(object, context, level)
    162         max_width = self._width - indent - allowance
    163         if len(rep) > max_width:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/pprint.py in _repr(self, object, context, level)
    391     def _repr(self, object, context, level):
    392         repr, readable, recursive = self.format(object, context.copy(),
--> 393                                                 self._depth, level)
    394         if not readable:
    395             self._readable = False

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)
    168     def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
    169         return _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level,
--> 170                           changed_only=self._changed_only)
    171 
    172     def _pprint_estimator(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context,

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _safe_repr(object, context, maxlevels, level, changed_only)
    412         if changed_only:
    413             params = _changed_params(object)
--> 414         else:
    415             params = object.get_params(deep=False)
    416         components = []

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/envs/py3env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/_pprint.py in _changed_params(estimator)
     96     init_params = {name: param.default for name, param in init_params.items()}
     97     for k, v in params.items():
---> 98         if (repr(v) != repr(init_params[k]) and
     99                 not (is_scalar_nan(init_params[k]) and is_scalar_nan(v))):
    100             filtered_params[k] = v

KeyError: 'base_score'

Name: xgboost
Version: 1.0.2

scikit-learn-0.23.0

pyhton 3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a bug with scikit-learn's update - check https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/5668 - guess it has been resolved.

Comment: Yes, that fix worked. You should be able to check the commit in the issue - that fixes the problem.

Comment: can you tell me the steps you followed to make it work